# Looping pages for scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-cleaning

My scraper for single page:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?padalinys%5B0%5D=76&page=1'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for h3 in soup.select('h3.list_h3'):
    job_title = h3.get_text(strip=True)
    company = h3.find_next(class_="heading_secondary").get_text(strip=True)
    salary = h3.find_next(class_="salary_amount").get_text(strip=True)
    location = h3.find_next(class_="list_city").get_text(strip=True)
    print('{:<50} {:<15} {:<15} {}'.format(company, salary, location, job_title))

    all_data.append({
        'Job Title': job_title,
        'Company': company,
        'Salary': salary,
        'Location': location
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')

#tips = sns.load_dataset('data.csv')
#print(tips)
```

Gives me a csv file but only with 50 rows.
I'm want to scrape all pages, was thinking to find in `HTML` code `'class=':'prev_next'` but both BACK and FORWARD are the same, only with different href. So I decided to make range loop and change page with it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?padalinys%5B0%5D=76&page=1'
#soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
all_data = []
for i in range(1, 9):
    url = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?padalinys%5B0%5D=76&page='+str(i)
    print(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    for h3 in soup.select('h3.list_h3'):
        try:
            job_title = h3.get_text(strip=True)
            company = h3.find_next(class_="heading_secondary").get_text(strip=True)
            salary = h3.find_next(class_="salary_amount").get_text(strip=True)
            location = h3.find_next(class_="list_city").get_text(strip=True)
            print('{:<50} {:<15} {:<15} {}'.format(company, salary, location, job_title))
        except AttributeError:
            
            all_data.append({
                    'Job Title': job_title,
                    'Company': company,
                    'Salary': salary,
                    'Location': location
                })
        
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

After running code it saves only 5 rows, so that's 10x less than code that I used just to scrape one page.

How would you loop pages? Pages are from `1` to `8`

And also how would clean Salary objects? as it comes as string which contains one of `Nuo 2700` or `Iki 2500` or has two numbers like `1000-3000`. Because I would like to use Salary column as integers so I could do some plotting with Seaborn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have indented the adding to the `all_data` list inside the `except` block. So, the control goes into `except` only if there is an exception. Running the following script gave around 365 rows in the csv file

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?padalinys%5B0%5D=76&page=1'
#soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
all_data = []
for i in range(1, 9):
    url = 'https://www.cvbankas.lt/?padalinys%5B0%5D=76&page='+str(i)
    print(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    for h3 in soup.select('h3.list_h3'):
        try:
            job_title = h3.get_text(strip=True)
            company = h3.find_next(class_="heading_secondary").get_text(strip=True)
            salary = h3.find_next(class_="salary_amount").get_text(strip=True)
            location = h3.find_next(class_="list_city").get_text(strip=True)
            print('{:<50} {:<15} {:<15} {}'.format(company, salary, location, job_title))
            all_data.append({
                    'Job Title': job_title,
                    'Company': company,
                    'Salary': salary,
                    'Location': location
                })
        except AttributeError:
            pass
            
        
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```